# Event for Chrome Google account logout or Google account user switch

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0, google-account

Is there an event or listener that fires when a user logs his Google account out of Chrome (or switches from account)?

When this happens I want to change my Chrome Extension default_icon (from green to red).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Fired when signin state changes for an account on the user's profile."

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/identity#event-onSignInChanged

Comment: Thank you so much, cannot believe I missed that. Works like a charm :-)